# lua, truncate string containing utf-8 encoded chars

Tags: utf-8, lua, truncate

I am doing a rewrite of an awk program that formats strings to be outputted to a status bar. I am not much of a programmer, just a hobbyist trying to learn in any downtime I get.

When truncating any non-ASCII  chars, e.g cyrillic (utf8) results in corrupted output, which displays as a series of question marks.

`Ouverture Il Ritorno dall'Estero op. 89  /  Mendelsshon  /  Великие �…  /  320 kb/s`

`string.len` and `#` count bytes, not chars. And a single cyrillic char is counted as 2 bytes rather than 1. This will obviously complicate truncating. Fortunently Lua 5.3 includes a [utf8 library](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#6.5), [wiki on unicode support](http://lua-users.org/wiki/LuaUnicode) to simplify working with non-acsii chars. I modified the "shorten" function to use `utf8.len` in order to get an accurate *character* count for truncating, but the issue persists.

```lua
--from penlight library, use utf8.len, not string.len
function shorten(s,w)
    local ellipsis = "…"
    local n_ellipsis = utf8.len(ellipsis)
    assert_string(1,s)
    if utf8.len(s) > w then
        return s:sub(1,w-n_ellipsis) .. ellipsis
    end
    return s
end
```

With further reading I learned utf8.offset should be used whenever truncating is a required.

> You should use these functions anywhere you need to manipulate text that you didn’t write yourself or may contain non-ASCII or non-English characters. If you truncate a string at a byte index that is not between whole codepoints you will end up with an invalid UTF-8 string that may render incorrectly or cannot be stored in a DataStore.
>
> If you are truncating a string at an index you should use string.sub with a byte index given by utf8.offset.

I have been trying to figure out how to use `utf8.offset` to get the needed byte index, but thus far have had zero success. If further context is helpful, here is my very wip [full script](https://pastebin.com/gK8XjLWW)

Any tips, code, criticism etc would be appreciated.

Comment: `return s:sub(1, utf8.offset(s, w - n_ellipsis + 1) - 1) .. ellipsis`

Comment: Very much appreciated @EgorSkriptunoff. That indeed resolved the issue :) A bit simpler than I anticipated as well. Right on.

Comment: Please remove your solution from the question and post it as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to [Egor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6834680/egor-skriptunoff) for the solution. In Lua 5.3:

```
return s:sub(1, utf8.offset(s, w - n_ellipsis + 1) - 1) .. ellipsis
```